# check table column name as string in where clause SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have some mapped column values stored in a table. I want an update query like ...

```
update table1 set table1.value = table2.columnValue 
from table2 
where table2's columnName = table1.ColumnNameValue
```

Comment: Share the mapping by which you identify which row in table2 will be mapped with table1's column..It can be done via dynamic query..

Answer (score 0):

Do a `JOIN` on both tables like

```
update t1 
set [value] = t2.columnValue
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.columnName = t1.ColumnName
```